# In apache qpid how to list the brokers status?

Tags: c++, apache, qpid

In [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/) how to list the brokers status?

I'm using `qpid-stat -b`:

```
Brokers
  broker  cluster       uptime   conn  sess  exch  queue
  ========================================================
  ?       <standalone>  17m 29s     1     1     8     5
```

Other than these any option is there?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by broker status. You may try `qpid-tool`. You can read more about it [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Messaging_User_Guide/sect-Messaging_User_Guide-Management_Tools-Using_qpid_tool.html) and also [here](http://qpid.apache.org/books/0.12/AMQP-Messaging-Broker-CPP-Book/html/ch02.html#MgmtC-2B-2B-Usingqpidtool).

> This utility provided a telnet style interface to be able to view,
>   list all stats and action all the methods. Simple capture below. Best
>   to just play with it and mail the list if you have questions or want
>   features added.

#### Example

```
% qpid-tool
Management Tool for QPID
qpid: list
Summary of Objects by Type:
    Package                 Class         Active  Deleted
    =======================================================
    org.apache.qpid.broker  exchange      8       0
    com.redhat.rhm.store    store         1       0
    org.apache.qpid.broker  broker        1       0
    org.apache.qpid.broker  binding       16      12
    org.apache.qpid.broker  session       2       1
    org.apache.qpid.broker  connection    2       1
    org.apache.qpid.broker  vhost         1       0
    org.apache.qpid.broker  queue         6       5
    org.apache.qpid.broker  system        1       0
    org.apache.qpid.broker  subscription  6       5
```